# SSL_connect certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl-certificate

I am getting SSL_connect error:

```
> ruby -ropen-uri -e 'eval open("https://git.io/vQhWq").read'
F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
        from F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:933:in `connect'
        from F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
        from F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
        from F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:319:in `open_http'
        from F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:737:in `buffer_open'
        from F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:212:in `block in open_loop'
        from F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `catch'
        from F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `open_loop'
        from F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:151:in `open_uri'
        from F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:717:in `open'
        from F:/Ruby/ruby/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

What I tried:

Followed [official instructions](https://bundler.io/v1.16/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#automated-ssl-check):

- Automated SSL Checked -> Failed
- Updated Bundler -> Successful (bundler-1.17.1)
- Updated Rubygems -> Successful (rubygems-2.7.8)
- Synced time -> Successful (time.windows.com)
- Updated CA certificates -> Replaced `F:\Ruby\ruby\lib\ruby\site_ruby\2.3.0\rubygems\ssl_certs\index.rubygems.org\GlobalSignRootCA.pem` with fresh [GlobalSignRootCA.pem](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/index.rubygems.org/GlobalSignRootCA.pem)
- Rerun Automated SSL Checked -> Failed

Some other solutions I am *NOT* interested in:

- Turn off verification: `http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`
- Adding `http://rubygems.org` to `gem sources`
- Set `SSL_CERT_FILE`. But why? As said in this [blog](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/ruby-ssl-error-certificate-verify-failed)

> Set SSL_CERT_FILE
>
> This isn't a bad solution if you know what you're
> doing. However, there are a lot of solutions out there that suggest
> downloading CA certificates to your machine and setting the
> SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable to its location.
>
> The problem with this approach is you don't know if you can trust the
> CA certificates you're downloading. In some cases, the CA certificates
> are even downloaded in clear text. Double trouble if you ask me.

I am on:

- Windows 10
- Ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]
- Rails 5.1.6.1
- gem 2.7.8 (recently upgraded)